# How to use opencv in embedded system

Tags: c++, opencv, embedded, shared-libraries, static-libraries

my question is related to the use of OpenCV in embedded systems. Instead of compiling the entire opencv library in my embedded platform, I would like to know if it is possible to copy only the libraries and call them from my .cpp main file.

Til now, what I usually do is to compile openCV in my embedded platform and in my main.cpp call

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

Then in my cmake file I just put:

```
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
target_link_libraries( main ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

This method works but I would like to save space and use only the .so or .a libraries. Is it possible to do that? if yes, how?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OpenCV will work fine, but you have to make sure a few things:

1. libraries that are being copied should be previously compiled for the same platform.
2. should be placed in the proper location.
3. you also need .h files for compiling your code.

Comment: you can make 2 embeded hardwares, 1st for developement which contain opencv compiled library with .h files and 2nd which just contain .so files for running your code

Comment: Hi Awais, thanks for your answer.
Basically:
1- I have to create a "lib" directory where I put all the .so files
2- I have to create a "include" directory where I put all the .h files
Then I have to call from cmake the opencv directory in the same way done previously?
thanks

Comment: i dont get you point "cmake the opencv directory"
you have to set the libraries path in the enviroment variable, otherwise it will give you errors.
or you can placed them in the OS lib folder.

Comment: I tought that I could do something like find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
target_link_libraries( main ${OpenCV_LIBS} ). setting also OpenCV in the environment viariable with export.